# .net create object instance from abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class TemplateBase
{
    public abstract string TemplateName { get; }
    public string RuntimeTypeName { get { return GetType().FullName; } }
    public abstract List<AreaContainer> TemplateAreas { get; }
}
```

then these 2 inherited classes:

```
public class SingleColumnTemplate : TemplateBase
{
    public override string TemplateName { get { return "Single column"; } }

    public AreaContainer CenterColumn { get; private set; }

    public SingleColumnTemplate()
    {
        this.CenterColumn = new AreaContainer("Middle");
    }

    private List<AreaContainer> templateAreas;

    public override List<AreaContainer> TemplateAreas
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.templateAreas == null)
            {
                this.templateAreas = new List<AreaContainer>() { this.CenterColumn };
            }

            return this.templateAreas;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TwoColumnTemplate : TemplateBase
{
    public override string TemplateName { get { return "Two column"; } }
    public AreaContainer LeftColumn { get; private set; }
    public AreaContainer RightColumn { get; private set; }

    public TwoColumnTemplate()
    {
        LeftColumn = new AreaContainer("Left");
        RightColumn = new AreaContainer("Right");
    }

    private List<AreaContainer> templateAreas;

    public override List<AreaContainer> TemplateAreas
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.templateAreas == null)
            {
                this.templateAreas = new List<AreaContainer>() { this.LeftColumn, this.RightColumn };
            }
            return this.templateAreas;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this class that is my model for editing:

```
public class ContentPage
{
    public virtual int ContentPageId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public TemplateBase Template { get; set; }
}
```

Question:

for my ActionResults I have the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    var row = new ContentPage();
    var template = new TwoColumnTemplate();        

    // Areas
    HtmlArea html_left = new HtmlArea();
    html_left.HtmlContent = "left area html content";

    HtmlArea html_right = new HtmlArea();
    html_right.HtmlContent = "right area html content";

    template.LeftColumn.Areas.Add(html_left);
    template.RightColumn.Areas.Add(html_right);

    row.Template = template;
    return View(row);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(ContentPage row)
{
    // Here i could loop through List -TemplateAreas and save each template Area to Db. I guess that would work

    return this.View(row);
}
```

Question:

For HttpGet- how would I load row Template from the database? since it could be SingleColumnClass or TwoColumnClass.

how would my ViewModel look like to solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the template type in you controller, so you can pass a parameter from the view to the controller, indicating the type (`SingleColumn` or `TwoColumn`). You could do this witn a `Enum`:

```
public enum TemplateType
{
   SingleColumn,
   TwoColumn
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(TemplateType templateType)
{
    var row = new ContentPage();
    TemplateBase template; 

    if (templateType == TemplateType.SingleColumn)
    {
        template = new SingleColumnTemplate();
    }
    else
    {
        template = new TwoColumnTemplate();
    }

    ...

    return View(row);
}
```

When you create the action link from your view you can specify:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit",
                    "Edit",
                    "YouController",
                    new 
                    { 
                        // singlecolumn or twocolumn
                        // depending on your concrete view
                        TemplateType = TemplateType.xxx 
                    },
                    null);
```

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid..the if else statements. I know what TemplateBase type is by:public string RuntimeTypeName { get { return GetType().FullName; } }
what would my db object look like? and how would it load into ContentPage without having if/else stuff..maybe using GetType()?  I found this:http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/plugin.html  but i'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @Shane: Sorry can you explain better?

Comment: Ok, i'm thinking that in my ActionResult for HTTPPost I would have the following:  [HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(ContentPage row)
{
    // I can get a list here ;
    foreach(var item in TemplateAreas) { // Save each area...}; Save 'row'
    return this.View(row);
}
the problem is HTTPGET..how would I load ContentPage abstract class? without doing the if/else stuff. thanks

Comment: @Shane: Please, could you update your post with the content of HttpPost?

Comment: HttpGet...meaning. ContentPage row = getfromrepository..; how would i load it from db into ContentPage?

Comment: In that case the database must know if the Template is single or twocolumn. I mean, you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: have to split it in 3 parts:             Type t = Type.GetType(row.Template.RuntimeTypeName);
            TemplateBase tempTemplate = (TemplateBase)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

Comment: var index = 0;
            // Get AreaContainer for template
            foreach (AreaContainer areaContainer in Repository.GetlistofAreaContainers(id Template) // This could be Single or TwoCol template
            {

Comment: tempTemplate.TemplateAreas.Add(AreaContainer);

                // Get HtmlContent for each AreaContainer
                foreach (HtmlArea item in Repository.GetListOfHtmlAreas(id of AreaContainer))
                {

Comment: // where index is index of just added AreaContainer 
                    tempTemplate.TemplateAreas.ElementAt(index).Areas.Add(item);
                }

                index += 1;
            }

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own Model Binder that is responsible for binding TemplateBase.  You will still need to have a way of knowing (in the model binder) which type you will be using a runtime, but you can always delegate that to a factory or service locator of some sort.  I did a quick google search and here is a blog post I found that gives you some information for making a model binder for a similar scenario:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bhaskarghosh/archive/2009/07/08/7143564.aspx

EDIT:  The blog leaves out how you tell MVC about your model binder.  When the application starts, you can add your model binder to `System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinders.Binders`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could do something like this?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(TemplateType templateType)
{
    var row = new ContentPage();
    TemplateBase template = (TemplateBase)Activator.CreateInstance(templateType);

    ...

    return View(row);
}
```

templateType would have to be the exact name of your inherited classes (you can ignore case)